# Does Matlab Coder produces single threaded C applications only?

Tags: c, multithreading, matlab, image-processing, matlab-coder

Is Matlab Coder only able to produce single threaded applications?

I attempted to convert some Matlab scripts, used for image analysis, and found that the code produced by Matlab Coder was much slower. This confused me because I thought the produced C code would be at-least as fast or faster then the M code. I then checked how many threads were being used for both the M code and the produced C code. The result was 1 thread used by the C code and there were many threads being used by the Matlab code. At this point I can only assume the image processing toolkit implements its function as mex functions which are multi-threaded.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730193/when-does-matlab-choose-to-thread-when-using-codegen-and-parfor
Another try is to use some compiler options like `-lpthread`

Comment: The matlab coder generates pragmas for openmp, maybe they where ignored during compile? Can you find any openmp related pragmas in your code? At least a parfor is translated to parallel code.

Answer (score 1):

While in general the generated code can be expected to be faster, there are some exceptions. Some implementations which are used by matlab are not available for generated code. I have no reference about the technical background, but I assume that these are fortran and/or assembler written libraries. An example for such a function is `eig` [which is known to produce different (correct) results in generated code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205736/matlab-codgen-eig-function-strange-behaviour/32212352#32212352)

The matlab coder comes with a code examples which [explains how a parfor is translated to openmp code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/examples/using-parfor-to-speed-up-an-image-contrast-enhancement-algorithm.html?refresh=true). As a first step make sure that your code contains the openmp relevant pragmas. If not try rewriting your code using a parfor loop.

In a last step, make sure that your compiler is configured to use openmp.